# How to set minimum and maximum margin left?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events

I wanna set my custom tag minimum and maximum margin-left. How can I do this?

I am using angular 2 and using a plugin angular-split. There I have a directive split-gutter. For that I need to set min and max margin-left.

Plunker follows

https://plnkr.co/edit/w8O2I3bD4bdXp0QsL35L?p=preview

I wanna restrict cursor move(splitting 2 panels) only for 50% to 70%. Means, I wanna set max and min margin-left to cursor.

`HTML`

```
<split direction="horizontal" style="position:relative;">
     <split-area size="70" >
          <p style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:50%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tiam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            <input type="button" value="Button" (click)="buttonClicked()">      

    </split-area>
    <split-area size="30" style="position:relative;">
            <p style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;z-index:1;background:red;">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eodolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
    </split-area>
</split>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ther is no built-in mechanism in the plugin to restrict the size of the areas.

What you can do is listen to the emitted [`dragProgress`](https://bertrandg.github.io/angular-split/#/documentation) event and check the size property of one area:

```
<split direction="horizontal" (dragProgress)="onDragProgress($event)">
    <split-area size="30">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tiam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </split-area>
    <split-area size="70">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eodolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
    </split-area>
</split>
```

You will have to reference the areas in your class and listen to the event:

```
@ViewChildren(SplitAreaDirective) areasEl: QueryList<SplitAreaDirective>

onDragProgress(event) {
   if (event.sizes[0] < 30) {
       this.areasEl._results[0].size = 30
   }

   if (event.sizes[0] > 50) {
       this.areasEl._results[0].size = 50
   }
}
```

[See live Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1dMu7mvkTPttKot4nOio?p=preview)